# Mandelbrot Set: Distance

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Assume I'm a 1-dimentional creature living on the boundary of Mandelbrot Set.
Is there a distance that I can define between two points say A and B on the boundary?

If Yes - can we generalize i.e. if you have a continuous line you can always define a distance between 2 points on the line?

Thanks

Comment: Without jumping into the second dimension, not really. The Mandelbrot set has infinite perimeter.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks. So is there a generalization i.e. which kind of boundary allows distance to be defined? (guess something like "roughness" - where Mandelbrot set is very rough and thus distance can't be defined vis-a-vis Circle which is "smooth"

Comment: I think the shape of which the boundary is from needs to be of integer dimension. For details on fractional dimension see [3B1B](https://youtu.be/gB9n2gHsHN4)